# pycharm / intellij - jupyter markdown not rendering

Tags: python, intellij-idea, markdown, pycharm, jupyter

I have installed the python plugin and it is not rendering the markdown in a jupyter notebook.

Same holds for pycharm.

I have also installed the additional markdown plugin.

Comment: Try their official channels before asking here, Jetbrains support staff is awesome.

Comment: Opened a ticket a while ago. No answer so far - will post the answer as soon as I get something

Comment: The ticket has been resolved a few days ago. Guys, we can give it a try.

Comment: Can you please share the ticket/ solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @VaibhavSharma A little bit late, but I posted an anwser.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue is fixed on more recent versions (>=2019) of Intellij, even though it [had a bug with JDK 11](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214343?_ga=2.180761316.2114542877.1608217043-836500196.1603908935), which would not show the markdown options.

To add the markup (according to this [Jetbrain's source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003368399-Adding-Markdown-cells-in-Jupyter-Notebook-Decorating-the-font)) one can use the option show on this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try downloading anaconda (scientific 'all inclusive' python package).
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

I use jupyter notebooks in there and markdown works.